# Equivalent of "make install" in the Java world

Tags: java, maven, ant, gradle, autotools

**TL;DR**: Is there a standard way in the Java world, to have the build tools install the executables they just built (like the `make install` of the C world)?

(I would be happy with a solution that would work only on Linux)

**More details**:

I have a Java project distributed via github. Compilation and dependencies are managed with maven 2. Running `mvn package` builds a tarball with my jar and the dependencies needed at runtime, plus an executable script which set the classpath and launch the main jar:

```
#!/bin/bash
cpBase="$(dirname "$0")"
java -cp "$cpBase/*" dw.cli.Program $@
```

So, if someone wants to install this on her computer, one need to:

- run `mvn package`
- and then to unpack the tarball and to copy the content in a directory on her `PATH`.

On the other hand I like the way the autotools are working: the user doesn't need to copy anything manually, because the build step `make install` handles the installation for her.

I could emulate this behaviour using `cp` through ant tasks in my `pom.xml`, but I'm more interested in learning the Java good practices than to provide non standard behaviors.

It seems [maven doesn't provide this behavior](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Getting+Started+with+Maven). On the other hand, I'm totally ignorant of what the other Java build tool can do wrt to this.

---

Edit:

As far as I understand `mvn install` and `mvn deploy` don't fit my need, because they will install my jar in my local or remote repository. Whereas I want to install my executables on my `PATH` (eg: to install my wrapper script in `/usr/local/bin`)

Comment: I might just not have understood the question, but why don't you  write a `Makefile` and put it in your project's root directory? With this, you could encapsulate all needed steps in an `install` task so that someone indeed just has to write `make install`.

Comment: Sure, I could add a Makefile (or an ad hoc shell script). I've just never seen, yet, a Java repo with this kind of setup, and I'd like to stick with Java common practices. I mean: when I clone a C repo, I seldom need to look at the README to know how to compile and install it, because it's always the same. I'm wondering if there are this kind of rules for Java too.

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged "gradle", so I'll supply the Gradle answer.

I take it you're building an application, not a library. In that case, Gradle is thoughtfully supplying the `application` plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
```

The plugin will supply you the `run`, `distZip`, `distTar` and `installDist` tasks, which do just what they sound like. Check out the documentation at 
[the official web site](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

Note that the installDist task doesn't, by default, put the software anywhere centrally on the system. Rather, it will install in a subdirectory of `build`, where temporary files are kept. You could set the `destinationDir` property on the task to remedy this.

Comment: I tagged it "Gradle" because I suspected it might bring a solution. Thanks for those pointers. I'm upvoting your answer this this link is valuable, and I'll dive in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can created a distribution archive (zip, tar.gz) which can be downloaded by the user and only needed to unpack and add the bin folder to the path.

The problem is that you can't automatically enhance you path environment variable. But if you use the generated scripts from appassembler-maven-plugin you can simply can call directly the generated scripts without enhancing your path. This works on linux as well as on windows.

This can be achieved by a combination of [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) and [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

The appassembler-maven-plugin will create the appropriate shell/bat/cmd files for you and the maven-assembly-plugin can create the appropriate archives (tar.gz, zip) for you.

As an example you can take a look here:

https://github.com/khmarbaise/supose/tree/master/supose-assembly

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question (since I distribute an archive instead of letting the build tool install the executable), however the appassembler plugin seems rather interesting. +1 for this pointer.

Answer (score 1):

"make install" works by copying your built artefacts into their target location. This behaviour is quite easy to emulate in ANT, because like make it allows you to specify your own build logic:

```
<target name="install" description="Copy binaries into install location">
  <mkdir dir="/opt/myapp/bin"/>
  <copy file="${dist.dir}/myproject.jar" todir="/opt/myapp/bin"/>
  <copy file="${dist.dir}/myproject.sh" todir="/opt/myapp/bin"/>
  <chown owner="${install.owner}">
    <fileset dir="/opt/myapp" include="**/*"/>
  </chown>
</target>
```

Course you'd have to run this target as root:

```
ant build
sudo ant install
```

Maven on the other hand is a highly opinionated build tool that does not support this kind of workflow. Why? This is really a deployment action. Of course you can customize the Maven setup using ant ANT plugin, but I'd advise to just have a shell script you run afterwards. Lot easier to understand:

```
mvn install
sudo install_myapp.sh
```

The script can pickup the built jar from the Maven local repository "$HOME/.m2/repository" or better still download it from a Maven repository!

Answer (score -1):

You have other mvn goals like 'mvn deploy' and 'mvn install' that do what you need.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't fit my needs. I just edited my question to explain why.

Comment: install installs the artifacts into the local repository and deploy transfers them to the remote repository.